# How to show a vector line and it corresponding value on a chart

Tags: excel, graph, charts, excel-formula

I want to create an interactive graph showing a vector between two coordinates (x,y)

I've done the graph and I have two points showing on it, but I  cannot create line between the two.

The picture shows sample two coordinates and the picture of a graph that I would want to create.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Create the coordinates for your orange line (columns F-H)

Choose and X-Y scatter plot.

Right click on the graph area and select choose data.

Edit series 1 and make sure you assign column C as your X values.  When I did this the automatic route it choose row 3 as the X values and that is not what you want.  Repeat for your Y values.

Add series 2 and manually select column F as you X values and column G as your Y values.

Left click on the second line and add data lables. you may need to do it twice to get all points to come up.  Select just the lables you want to keep then hit delete.  Select a lable you want to keep and then modify its properties on the right side.  For lable information to display select from range and select H3 to H7

Edit the chart title to suit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you added points in columns E and F manually? I was hoping the orange line could somehow appear automatically without any other input that X&Y cords.

Comment: I added formulas in column E, so that if you changed your coordinates, column E would up date as well as your magnitude values at the mid point.  As far as I know there is no automatic way of getting any of the information displayed solely for the orange line above.